# How to re-populate the Dynamic ng-model fields when value from ng-repeat in Angularjs using ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic framework to build an app. In my form i need to  re-populate the dynamic ng-model input field. I refer " [How to create Dynamic ng-model in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517046/how-to-create-dynamic-ng-model-in-angular) " to create the dynamic ng-model field. it works. But when i'm trying to re-populate that field it was not working (I need to perform CRUD opearation).

My HTML part is:

```
<div class="row header">
  <div class="col col-40">Name</div>
  <div class="col col-60">Marks</div>
</div>

<div class="row" ng-repeat="(key, user) in userList">
  <div class="col col-40" ng-bind="user.name"></div>
  <div class="col col-60">
    <input type="text" name="actual_marks" ng-model="markscardData.actual_marks[user.user_id]" placeholder="Please enter the marks" />
  </div>
</div>
```

My controller is like this

```
.controller('MarkscardAddCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $state, $http, $ionicPopup, baseUrl) 
{
  $scope.markscardData = {};


  $http.get(baseUrl+"api_method=markscard.getUserList&api_version=1.0&app_key=12345&  course_id="+course+"&subject_id="+subject+"&  markscard_id="+markscard).then(function(response){
  $scope.userList = response.data.responseMsg;
  });  
})
```

The JSON value in $scope.userList like this

```
  [{"name":"Harshith","user_id":"249","actual_marks":"76","min_marks":"40","max_marks":"100"},{"name":"Nithin","user_id":"246","actual_marks":"60","min_marks":"40","max_marks":"100"},{"name":"Prathik","user_id":"247","actual_marks":"70","min_marks":"40","max_marks":"100"},{"name":"Ravee","user_id":"250","actual_marks":"80","min_marks":"40","max_marks":"100"},{"name":"Shivarama","user_id":"248","actual_marks":"90","min_marks":"40","max_marks":"100"}]
```

I need markscardData.actual_marks[user.user_id] repopulate when form is open in edit mode and it allow  update also. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing a lot of code in your controller, there are variables that simply aren't defined, the model is not created, we need the whole example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are losing data when you reload the page. This is happening because the dynamic ng-models are not actually bound in your controller.
If you want to load actual marks from the JSON you received,

```
for(var i in userList){
    $scope.markscardData.actual_marks[userList[i].user_id] = userList[i].actual_marks;
}
```

put this line below `$scope.userList = response.data.responseMsg;`.
This should initialize your dynamic models if applicable.
Also, you will need to put these two declarations at the start:
`$scope.markscardData = {};
$scope.markscardData.actual_marks = [];`

Hope this works for you .. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its works for me. Now the code is $scope.markscardData = {};
$scope.markscardData.actual_marks = [];

        $http.get(baseUrl+"api_method=markscard.getUserList&api_version=1.0&app_key=12345&course_id="+course+"&subject_id="+subject+"&markscard_id="+markscard).then(function(response){

          $scope.userList = response.data.responseMsg.result;

          for(var i in $scope.userList){
            console.log($scope.markscardData.actual_marks[$scope.userList[i].user_id] = $scope.userList[i].actual_marks);
          }

        }); and same html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually sure what you're issue as as the code you've provided with the code in the response should work fine:

Assuming you're just trying to update the values of the fields, then I'd create a method that you can call, with the array of users as it's parameter, and then mess with the model you've created called `markscardData`.

```
this.markscardData = {
   actual_marks  : {}
}
this.updateList = function(newList) {
   angular.forEach(newList, function(user) {
        if (!user || !user.user_id) return;     
        ctrl.markscardData.actual_marks[user.user_id] = user.actual_marks;
   });
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/qvw9bmhe/35/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see the jsfiddle you created. But  ng-model="markscardData.actual_marks[user.user_id]"  field is not re-populated.

Comment: Have you clicked the button 'update', it update the value of the first field from the `updatedList` array

Comment: Sorry i'm not noticed. Thanks for giving extra knowledge on this. I mean in update the form field. I'm just started working with angulajs with ionic framework. thanks for the reply

Comment: If my answer has helped you please tick the button above making my answer the correct answer

Comment: definitely it help me.