# Angular 6 - How to read values of dynamic ng-model?

Tags: angular, ngmodel

This [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517046/how-to-create-dynamic-ng-model-in-angular?answertab=votes#tab-top) is working to display many inputs. But values are not readed.

in my html, I added:

```html
<div class="item_key" *ngFor="let x of demo">
    <span class="key_span">Value</span>
    <input [(ngModel)]="teller[x.id]"  class="add_key">
</div>
<pre>{{teller | json}}</pre>
```

in my ts file, I added:

```
teller = {};
    demo = [{
        'id': 1
    }, {
        'id': 2
    }];
```

But the teller still as {}

Comment: work fine for me https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bfqney?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case, it was not working because I have some others inputs which have [(ngModel)]="model.someLabel"

Comment: update the demo

Comment: try use trackBy index in ngfor loop